# Command 'ionic' is not performed

Tags: ionic-framework

Please, help with such trouble:

I am working at Windows10, installed everything properly (I mean Java JDK, Apache Ant, Android SDK with env vars and paths).

Then i ran command - `npm install -g ionic`. Ionic was installed well.

Then I created directory "ionic", passed into this dir and ran command `"ionic start todo blank"`.

I got - `"ionic" is not the internal or external command`, ...

OK.. I went into my env path and wrote the path that I got after installing ionic

```
C:\Users\Washington\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic
```

But it does not work :(

Answer (score 0):

resolved - right path is C:\Users\Washington\AppData\Roaming\npm\